# Which complex polynomials in 3 variables are $GL_3(\Bbb{C})$ invariant?

Tags: polynomials, invariance

A polynomial $p(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ is $GL_3(\Bbb{C})$-invariant if
$$ \forall \sigma \in GL_3(\Bbb{C}): p(\sigma(x,y,z)) = p(x,y,z).$$

How to characterize the set of $GL_3(\Bbb{C})$ invariant polynomials ?

Comment: So one way to attempt to find this is as follows: 
Write $p(x,y,z)=\sum_{i,j,k}a_{ijk}x^iy^jz^k$ and $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}\\ b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}\\ b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$. Then you can write out $p(\sigma(x,y,z))=p(x,y,z)$ which will give you some conditions on the coefficients of the polynomial $p$. 

I hope that by choosing some easy $\sigma$'s, you can significantly reduce the possibilities. This is a brute force way, but I don't see a clever way of doing this immediately.

Comment: Maybe it's instructional to try to solve the easier problem $p(\sigma(x))=p(x)$ for $\sigma\in GL_1(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the easier problem only has constant polynomials as solutions, I expect the same for your problem. So where did you encounter this definition?

Answer (score 1):

Only the constant polynomials are $GL_3(\Bbb{C})$-invariant.
Let us take $p(x,y,z)$ and write it in powers of $x$:
$$ p(x,y,z) = \sum_{i=0}^n x^i Q_i(y,z),$$
where $Q_n$ is non zero.
Let $\sigma \in GL_3(\Bbb{C})$ be defined by 
$$ \sigma(x,y,z) := (x+y,y,z).$$
Now
$$ p \circ \sigma (x,y,z) = p(x,y,z) + n x^{n-1} y Q_n(y,z) + \mbox{ lower order terms in } x.$$
But since $Q_n$ is not zero, this cannot equal $p$.
Thus we cannot have a polynomial which involves $x$, and is invariant even under $\sigma$, let alone under all of $GL_3(\Bbb{C})$. 
The same holds, of course, for all other variables, and so the only invariant polynomials are the constants.

Comment: This is correct, and more or less what I expected. Your solution is a bit more elegant than the brute force method I suggested. Good job.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. This seems to generalize to $n$ variable polynomials, and to $GL_n$, and even to any field, at least of characteristic $0$.

Comment: You can also see this by using the fact that $GL_3$ is acting (almost) transitiv. So as soon as a polynomial takes two different values (i.e. is not constant) it will not be invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on a remark by Maik Pickl:

Assume $p(x,y,z)$ is a non constant polynomial. Then there exist at least two points, $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2) \in \Bbb{C}^3$, (with $x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2 \neq 0$), such that
$$ p(x_1,y_1,z_1) \neq p(x_2,y_2,z_2). $$
Let $\tau \in GL_3(\Bbb{C})$ be defined by
$$ \tau(x,y,z) := (\frac{x_2}{x_1} x,\frac{y_2}{y_1} y,\frac{z_2}{z_1} z).$$
Now
$$p\circ \tau (x_1,y_1,z_1) = p(x_2,y_2,z_2) \neq p(x_1,y_1,z_1),$$
hence $p$ is not $\tau$-invariant, and cannot be $GL_3(\Bbb{C})$-invariant.